# Where is targetError attribute handled

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, force-recorddata

This is rather a generic question but I cannot find anything in documentation or communities:
Where is the targetError attribute variable (in below example `error`) set/handled for a recordDataset

```
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecordDataCmp"
recordId="{!v.recordId}" 
layoutType="{!v.layout}"
targetRecord="{!v.record}"
targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
targetError="{!v.error}"
recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" />
```

when e.g. `event.getParams().changeType == ERROR` and can I intervene (set custom Error Message etc)?
Only thing Trailhead gives me as explanation is:

> The targetError attribute is set to a localized error message if an
>   error occurs on load.

What does above line mean exactly?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you refer to the [Aura Component developer guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/data_service_handling_errors.htm), You will get more details on it:-

### Handle Errors For force:recordData

> To act when an error occurs, handle the recordUpdated event and handle
>   the case where the changeType is “ERROR”.

Example: -Declare that your component handles the recordUpdated event.

```
<force:recordData aura:id="forceRecord"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    layoutType="FULL"
    targetRecord="{!v._record}"
    targetFields="{!v.simpleRecord}"
    targetError="{!v._error}"
    recordUpdated="{!c.recordUpdated}" />
```

Implement an action handler that handles the error.

```
({
  recordUpdated: function(component, event, helper) {

    var changeType = event.getParams().changeType;

    if (changeType === "ERROR") { /* handle error; do this first! */ }
    else if (changeType === "LOADED") { /* handle record load */ }
    else if (changeType === "REMOVED") { /* handle record removal */ }
    else if (changeType === "CHANGED") { /* handle record change */ }
})
```

If an error occurs when the record begins to load, targetError is set to a localized error message. An error occurs if:

- Input is invalid because of an invalid attribute value, or
  combination of attribute values. For example, an invalid recordId, or
  omitting both the layoutType and the fields attributes.
- The record isn’t in the cache and the server is unreachable
  (offline).

If the record becomes inaccessible on the server, the recordUpdated event is fired with changeType set to "REMOVED." No error is set on targetError, since records becoming inaccessible is sometimes the expected outcome of an operation. For example, after lead convert the lead record becomes inaccessible.

Records can become inaccessible for the following reasons.

- Record or entity sharing or visibility settings restrict access.
- Record or entity is deleted.

When the record becomes inaccessible on the server, the record’s JavaScript object assigned to targetRecord is unchanged.

Comment: Thanks, but this unfortunately doesn't answer the core question "where is the targetError attribute variable set/handled" (and how). It just cites stuff we already know.